# JPA- Hibernate - ID values generated from Select statement

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am having problems mapping a legacy database schema using JPA annotations.

The schema uses a table to generate unique IDs for most of the tables in the db - it has a structure of:

```
table_name
column_name
next_id
block_size
```

To get new unique ID for a record insert, you run a select like:

```
SELECT next_id FROM tbl_next_id WHERE table_name = 'tbl_pets' and column_name = 'pet_id'
```

urrgh.  I know I could do this in pure hibernate by using a 'select' id generator (unless I just dreamt that up) - can anyone recommend the best way of handling this with JPA annotations?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing better than this:

```
@TableGenerator(name="petsgen",
      table="tbl_next_id",
      pkColumnName="table_name",
      pkColumnValue="tbl_pets",
      valueColumnName="next_id",
      allocationSize=1
)

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="petsgen")
```

Will of course not support combination of table name + column name, but should work as long as there is only one generator for table.

Answer (score 1):

[TableGenerator](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/TableGenerator.html) does something similar, but not exactly. There is no support for column_name and block_size. Maybe you can extend that generator to take care of it.